# Redhat alternative for AIX chitab

Tags: redhat, inittab

From AIX, we are moving to Redhat Linux. In our shell scripts we have used AIX chitab command to modify /etc/inittab file. But in Redhat Linux, don't see any command to modify /etc/inittab file.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, there is no equivalent in Linux, because you can edit the file directly

```
vi /etc/inittab

## if you dont want to reboot, do the following
init q
```